# Bash: $? returns 1 when it should be 0

Tags: bash

I have a bash script with the line

```
klist | grep DHCPTEST.COM > /dev/null
```

I know that klist will return lines with DHCPTEST.COM so I know that grep should return true (0) and when the script is run from the command prompt $? does indeed return 0.

However, when the script is called from a C program (DHCPD), the line returns False (i.e $? is set to 1) - Why?

Comment: how are you determining the results when called from C? Is that `system`? `execve`? `execvpe`? Are you specifying `bash` or could it use `/bin/sh`? How do you know what the line returns anyway?

Comment: If you can spare the effort, please _do share_ the code you use the run the command. I suspect the execution might not even succeed, yielding an error as if there was no match.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any confusion, spell it out:

```
grep -q DHCPTEST.COM <(klist)
```

Most likely any differences in behaviour are due to

- a different shell (bash, dash, sh?) being invoked
- different subshell behaviours (a pipe will *usually* invoke a subshell. I'd personally have to look up what exit code gets returned (the one from `klist` or the one from `grep`)

Using the above, you avoid the possible ambiguity by replacing pipes with command substitution

Comment: I have tried both the bash shell and the sh shell ( the code that is calling the script is using the exec command and that seems to use a Bourne shell). As the $? is returned from the last command executed, I would expect it to be from the grep command and, as I said, the script when executed from the command line does return a 0 value from that line; it is only when the scrip is called from the C program that the return value changes.

Comment: I'm sure POSIX has something to say there, but it cannot be said to be completely obvious that 'As the $? is returned from the last command executed` that implies it will return the `grep` exitcode: The participating processes of a pipe are run in parallel, i.e. simultaneously. I'm sure POSIX will mandate a certain logic with regards to $?, but like I said, it is not obvious and I would have to look it up myself.

Comment: I tried your method and $? is still set to 0 when the script is executed from command line and 1 when called from DHCPD.

Comment: In that case, I'm suspecting locale differences (different collation orders result in different comparison results). Can you check the value of the `LANG` environment variable (PS. _This actually assumes that you might be searching for something a little less trivial than `DHCPTEST.COM` - but in any case, it is worth a check_)

Comment: The result of LANG is en_GB.utf8.

Comment: No, interestingly, when called from the DHCPD.CONF file, the script outputs en_US.UTF-8.